# How can i call rowData value in array object on Render Method React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I used to call https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-slider 
and basic example is

```
    <ImageSlider
          images={[
               'www.url.com/abc.png',
               'www.url.com/abc.png',
               'www.url.com/abc.png',
                  ]}
    />
```

---

but in my code i want to call url from rowData like this but imageslider can't display image

```
<ListView
            enableEmptySections={true}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={
              (rowData) =>
                    <ImageSlider
                             images={[

                                  {rowData.image_fields1},

                                  {rowData.image_fields2},

                                  {rowData.image_fields3},

                                    ]}

                                />

            }
          />
```

---

When i insert single quote **'{rowData.image_fields1}'** it returns missing syntax

Comment: why do need to inser quote? Whne you use  {rowData.image_fields1},what is the output

Answer (score 0):

The expected type of images prop is array of string, but you are setting array of object in your code.

Change your code to:

```
renderRow={
  (rowData) =>
    <ImageSlider
      images={[rowData.image_fields1, rowData.image_fields2, rowData.image_fields3]}
    />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `{}` around the `rowData` here.

This should work:

```
<ListView
            enableEmptySections={true}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={
              (rowData) =>
                    <ImageSlider
                             images={[ 
                                  rowData.image_fields1,

                                  rowData.image_fields2,

                                  rowData.image_fields3,

                                    ]}

                                />

            }
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var value = 'abc';
var arr = [value];
var arr1 = [{value}];

console.log(arr)//output will be string
console.log(arr1)//output will be object
```

Use this way:  `rowData.image_fields1`

```
images={[

         rowData.image_fields1,

        rowData.image_fields2,

        rowData.image_fields3,

      ]}
```